# HTML5 input type range from positive to negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to allow a positive minimum and a negative maximum? I am trying to create the slider in log space (10^8-10-13) and want to show the exponent on the slider.

```
<input  type="range" min="8" max='-13' value="1" step="-1" id="myRange" >
```

This currently reverts to the default `max=100` value.

Or perhaps can I reverse the slider in some way? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: To help make this less confusing... OP wants the 8 to appear on the left side and the -13 to appear on the right side. The CSS answer by Pierre Tassel below is very clever.

EDIT: Please remember I want the scale to be DECREASING from 8 to -13 (log space 10^8-10^-13).

EDIT: In IDL xr=[8,-13] (or R xlim=c(8,-13)). Note that the minimum value is a positive and the max is a negative number, and you can step between the two accordingly. I am asking for help with a workaround to create the same behaviour with the input type range.

Comment: can you tell us a number which is greater than 8 and less than -13? you should swap the min max value to make this work.

Comment: Lolz dude -13 is smaller than 8 you should put `min='-13'` and `max='8'`

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I want the scale to begin at 8 and decrease to -13

Comment: The downvote seems unfair, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Making the step negative does not change the laws of arithmetic: it does not make a negative number larger than a positive number. You are probably thinking of `min` and `max` as “start” and “end” of a scale as you run through it. But that’s not what they mean. You have not explained what you expect to gain by using `min` and `max` that way.

Comment: Turn the slider upside-down with `transform`?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I am asking for a workaround, as stated in the original question, so that I can use 'min' as the larger of the two numbers and decrement it with each step.

Comment: Scale the slider from 0 to 21 with step=1. In the change handler, calculate `8 - $(this).val()` to give the scaliing you actually want.

Comment: And yes, downvotes are not justified.

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ke8k66jp/1/)

Comment: The question still does not describe what the goal is. Even after last edit, it says just that you want a workaround for some behavior that is not described in the question.

Comment: would be great for HTML to incorporate a range direction... descending/ascending... vertical/horizontal... BUT if CSS can handle that just fine... not bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply switch the limits and multiply the value by `-1`:

```
<input  type="range" min="-8" max='13' value="1" step="1" id="slider" >

$('#slider').change(function(){
    var val = -+($(this).val());
    console.log(val);
});
```

If you'll need the value to be submitted, copy it to a hidden field, and use that on server-side instead of the original.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1c0xqm5/).

Answer (score 8):

This slider will be reversed: min(left) is 8 and max(right) is -13, i think this is what you wanted... and step=-1 don't works.
HTML:

```
<input type="range" min="-13" max="8" value="1" step="1" id="range"/>
```

css:

```
#range{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Thx css!

Comment: Thanks Pierre! Looks good to me, that's wonderfully simple! I'll have a play around with the rest of the site and see if it's a good fit before I accept.

Comment: I wouldn't want to rely on this without thorough testing in many browsers/versions. There's bound to be issues somewhere.

Comment: If you're looking for compatibility, ie supports it as it supports slider inputs, since ie9 prefixed and ie10 universal: [w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: This is a better answer than needing to write a value transform. Suppose you wanted the slider value to show in output tag: with this simple CSS trick the value will be correct, but not with the value transform techniques. Also if you directly query the slider you will get correct value; not so with the other proposed solutions.

Comment: to change the slider colors we can use http://danielstern.ca/range.css - the default style looks bad cos after `rotateY(180deg)`, the "lower fill" color is on the "wrong" side

Answer (score 1):

Scale the slider from 0 to 21 with step=1.

In the change handler, calculate `8 - $(this).val()` to give the scaling you actually want.

**HTML**

```
<input type="range" min="0" max='21' value="7" step="1" id="myRange">
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#myRange').change(function () {
    var scaledValue = 8 - $(this).val();
    console.log(scaledValue);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ke8k66jp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have added the condition which is not going to satisfy logically. You need to swap the min and max value to make slider work:

```
 <input type="range" min="-13" max='8' value="1" step="1" id="myRange" >
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ke8k66jp/)**

Comment: I want the scale to be decreasing (min = left-side of scale) from 8 to -13. The question is whether anyone can suggest a workaround. step=-1 doesn't seem to help (it increments absolute step value)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to allow a positive minimum and a negative maximum, but for the given case we can use min = -8 and max = 13 and on change we will assign negative of range value in a variable. e.g.,

```
<script>
var exponent=1;
</script>
<input  type="range" min="-8" max='13' value="-1" step="1" id="myRange" onchange="document.exponent = - this.value;">
```