# How to reverse the direction in HTML5 range input?

Tags: html

To have a slidebar in HTML5, we may use range input. i.e.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max='5' value="0" step="1" >
```

The default behavior is to have minimum value on the left side and maximum value on the right side. Is there a way I can put the maximum value on the left side instead?

I know I can do that with Javascript. Is there a way to do that with HTML alone?

---

**Reply to "possible duplicate question":**

That question accept javascript solution, and I am asking for HTML only solution. I think it is obvious that it is not a duplication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 input type range from positive to negative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794439/html5-input-type-range-from-positive-to-negative)

Comment: It's not the accepted answer, but there's a CSS solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27794806/362536

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This might do the trick: setting the direction of the input to be right to left on the CSS

```
#reversedRange {
  direction: rtl
}
```

**See sample code below**:

PS the javascript/jquery code is only to illustrate the values changing and it's not needed.  Only the CSS and the `id` attribute on the `input` element

**Updated:**  based on comments by @MCTaylor17 (thanks)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#rangeValue").text($("#reversedRange").val());
  
  $("#reversedRange").on('change input', function() {
    $("#rangeValue").text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```css
#reversedRange {
  direction: rtl
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Max<input type="range" min="0" max='5' value="0" step="1" id="reversedRange">Min
<div>value: <span id="rangeValue"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one for the `direction: rtl` property. Not pure HTML, but at least much better than those javascript solution. And at least it is short enough to put in inline style.

Comment: Nice trick.  FYI, if you add "input" to the events (eg `.on("change input"`) it will update in real-time.

Answer (score 8):

This is simply do with **CSS** and pure **JavaScript**. I hope this snippet will help you.

CSS & HTML

```css
input{
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
Max<input type="range" min="0" max='5' value="0" step="1" onmousemove="document.getElementById('Range_Value').innerHTML=this.value" onchange="document.getElementById('Range_Value').innerHTML=this.value">Min

<h3>Value: <span id="Range_Value">0</span></h3>
```

Comment: The downside of this solution is that keyboard input is reversed - the left arrow moves the thumb to the right, and the right arrow moves the thumb to the left.

Comment: Why would you do this when you can simply do `direction: rtl`? The other solution is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without changing the way the range looks or works:

```js
$("#reversedRange").on('change input', function() {
  var output = Math.abs($(this).val());
  $("#rangeValue").text(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="range" min="-5" max='0' value="-5" step="1" id="reversedRange">

<h3>Selected Value is: <span id="rangeValue"></span></h3>
```

Comment: I was asking for solution without using javascript, else there are already many similar questions out there and this one would have been marked as duplicated question.

Comment: You can use this without javascript, I just added it to display the result. You need to handle the form data at some point anyway, so there you can easily transform the negative value into something you can use.

Comment: Um.... I wonder if that javascript is just for display, as it seems the `* -1` is necessary?

Comment: It's just removing the `-` from the value, because the slider returns a value from -5 to 0. You could also use `Math.abs()` on the frontend, or do that it in whatever language you use on the backend to process the data from your form.

Comment: I will remove the -1, as that `* -1` can be moved to be done in backend, but I must say the CSS solution is much better, especially when you need to handle negative values as well.