# Highlight the right instead of the left of an input type="range"

Tags: javascript, css, range, slider

I have an input of type range. Normally this enables a user to create a range of values. Maybe the min value is 0 and max is 100 and the start value is 50. So that means the range is from 0 to the number you choose and so the left side of the slider has a color. In other words the number you are choosing is a maximum of the range but what if you want it to be a minimum?

I know there are plenty of videos on how to reverse input. I don't want change the numbers just highlight the right side of the slider. How can I do this?

It is actually working in the code snippet here

[How to reverse the direction in HTML5 range input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275891/how-to-reverse-the-direction-in-html5-range-input)

But I don't know how they do it.

This the code for my from custom slider.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  height: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slider {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #280dd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is in your link. If forget about jquery. You need to rotate an input tag. However you need to count value on js or a backside.

Comment: ok great thanks for your help with this question.